# Sql data loading blank row errors

Tags: sql, database, excel, oracle

I have an Excel file that contains some data that needs loading into my sql script. I have gotten most of it done but I am coming up against a problem due to the spreadsheet. The spreadsheet has data in rows that is implicit from the one above it (see the picture below).

Does anyone have any idea of how I can do this? Links to other pages would be welcome,I just wouldn't know how to start searching for this.

[image: Excel Spreadsheet]

Comment: it would be easier to edit excel files and fill the blank rows with data. So focuse how to atotmate it

Comment: Here's link on how to fill in the blank rows with values in previous filled cells: http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/fill-the-empty-cells-left-by-pivot-table-row-fields/. You can turn on the Macro Recorder, do that action, and then fiddle with the resulting code.

Answer (score 0):

Quick way to fill the blanks in Excel:

- Select the table
- Hit <kbd>F5</kbd>
- Click <kbd>Special</kbd>
- Tick "Blanks" and hit <kbd>OK</kbd>

All blank cells in the table are now selected. Without changing the selection,

- type a = sign
- hit the up arrow key on your keyboard.
- Hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Now all previously blank cells contain a formula that references the cell right above. Copy the table and paste it over itself with Paste Special > Values to replace the formulas with the values.

Far less key strokes than writing a macro, and faster in the processing, too.